# Why does PHP not throw an error when I pass too many parameters to a function?

Tags: php, function, methods

I am a n00b at php. I was learning about Default Parameters so I made this function.

```
function doFoo($name = "johnny"){
    echo "Hello $name" . "<br />";
}
```

I made these calls

```
doFoo();
doFoo("ted");
doFoo("ted", 22);
```

The first two printed what was expected i.e

```
Hello johnny
Hello ted
```

but the third call also printed

```
Hello ted
```

I was expecting an error, after all the function is made for one argument whereas I am calling it with two arguments.
Why was there no error?

Comment: because in php you can use this kind of function: http://it.php.net/func_get_args

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is *not wrong* to pass more arguments to a function than needed.

You only get error if you pass to few arguments.

```
function test($arg1) {
 var_dump($arg1);
}

test();
```

**Above will result in following error:**
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function...

If you want to fetch first argument plus all others arguments passed to function you can do:

```
function test($arg1, ...$args) {
 var_dump($arg1, $args);
}

test('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

**Resulting in:**
string(5) "test1"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test3"
}

Comment: This is wrong, at least in 2021. Passing more than the expected args to a function throws an error. See this example on `intval()` when passing more than 2 args: `PHP Warning:  intval() expects at most 2 parameters, 4 given in /path/to/file.php on line XXX`

Answer (score 20):

PHP doesn't throw an error on function overload.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a really poor answer. Function/method overloading means having multiple methods with the same name but with different parameter signatures. It DOES NOT mean accepting a call to a method with too many parameters and just dropping off the extra parameters that don't fit the signature. The reason PHP accepts more parameters than called for in a method is a fundamental flaw in the language, not a result of any recognized programming syntactical practice.

Answer (score 7):

because PHP functions support variable number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently because that's how PHP programmers like it.  There was a String Argument Count RFC to emit a Notice when too many arguments are sent, but it was soundly rejected, to my dismay: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_argcount

Answer (score -7):

It should only print a notice, but no error.
I think you have your error reporting set up so that notices are not shown on screen.

Try pasting this at the top of your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this is incorrect. Even when setting the strictest error reporting setting there will be no notices.

Comment: This is not a wrong answer. Since the error is a warning, very well the error reporting statement does influence the visible error. This is in fact the probable right answer. Upvoted.