# Results aren't ordered

Tags: yii2, sql-order-by

The following query returns all records, but they are not in descending order. It seems the query is unaffected by the second parameter of orderBy.

```
\app\models\Lookup::find()->orderBy('id',SORT_DESC)->all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do the orderBy like a single string parameter:

```
\app\models\Lookup::find()->orderBy('id SORT_DESC')->all()
```

or as an array with key => value:

```
\app\models\Lookup::find()->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])->all()
```

Comment: thanks @hreitsma, it seems php doesn't throw an error on function overload as mentioned in: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928707/why-does-php-not-throw-an-error-when-i-pass-too-many-parameters-to-a-function)